# Jest Unexpected Token "{"

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, graphql, jestjs

recurro a su ayuda porque no he podido solucionarlo investigando por mi cuenta, recien empece a crear un mini proyecto, es absolutamente nuevo, lo unico que tiene es `apollo-server-express` y un pequeno esquema hecho con `gql` tag, quise configurar jest para practicar y aprende `TDD` pero no logro solucionar este error por mas que busco.

Agradeceria muchisimo si pudiesen ayudarme

**Error**

```
Details:

    /mnt/c/Users/Horo/code/express-sv/src/graphql/schema.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { gql } from "apollo-server-express";
                                                                                                    ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

**Jest Config**

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest",
  }
};
```

**Test file**

```
import app from '../src/index';
import * as supertest from 'supertest';
describe('app', () => {
  let request;
  beforeEach(() => {
    request = supertest(app);
  });
  it('should return a successful response for GET /', done => {
    request.get('/')
      .expect(200, done);
  });
});
```

**WebPack**

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');

const {
  NODE_ENV = 'production',
} = process.env;

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  mode: NODE_ENV,
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [
          'ts-loader',
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: [ nodeExternals() ],
  plugins: [
    new WebpackShellPlugin({
      onBuildEnd: ['yarn run:dev']
    })
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sino me equivoco estás usando Babel para soportar la sintaxis de `import/export`. Creo que tu problema es que Jest no está usando Babel para entender la sintaxis más reciente. Lo que necesitas es instalar [`babel-jest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-jest)

Creo que esta [parte de la documentación](https://jestjs.io/docs/es-ES/getting-started#usando-babel) es lo que necesitas.